# Need help receiving and listing the values of an array variable after receiving it from a form

Tags: php

i have this in buy.php

```
<form action="cart.php">
    <?php 
    echo'<input style="width:10px; margin-left:9px; " name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $variety['price']. '"  />
         <input name="variety[]" type="hidden" value="' . $variety['variety']. '"  />';
    ?>
</form>
```

Then to receive in cart.php I do it like

```
<?php
$aDoor= $_POST['price'];
$aDoor1= $_POST['variety'];
?>
```

$aDoor is a string and $aDoor are numbers

to sum the numbers I can easily script it inside cart.php like:

```
echo "Sum of vlues = ".array_sum($aDoor);
```

But how can I list the strings inside of $aDoor1 at the left of the prices $aDoor? and to place the sum of values script above below the $aDoor as the prices total?

Since $aDoor1 is an array i have use a foreach loop to list each item but then it will only print the word array instead of the actual values of the array variable $aDoor1

```
foreach($aDoor1 as $variety) {
echo '<div>'.$variety['variety']. '</div>
}
```

Thank you, Don't know that much of php

Comment: Don't ever build an application where money gets passed around unless you really, really know what you're doing.

Comment: Can please show the output of `print_r($_POST['price'])` and `print_r($_POST['variety'])` ?

Comment: @Matchu What do mean by an build an application where money gets passed around?

@felix the output is 
Array ( [price] => Array ( [0] => 20.30 [1] => 25.90 )
[variety] => Array ( [0] => Small Tray [1] => Medium Tray [2] => Large Tray ) 
[formSubmit_x] => 66 [formSubmit_y] => 4 [formSubmit] => Submit )

Comment: The fact that you have `cart.php` implies that there are going to be monetary transactions on your website. Unless you are a PHP pro, you *must* leave this job to the professionals. There are plenty of PHP e-commerce solutions out there, so use those unless you can be 100% sure that neither you nor your customers will be cheated because of something you don't yet know about PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you aren't specifying it, when you create form elements using the `[]` syntax after their name PHP automatically translates that into an array with auto-generated incrementing indexes (0, 1, 2, 3, etc).  You can reference the array index of each of your elements as they will be matching for paired form fields:

```
foreach($aDoor1 as $index => $variety) {
  echo '<div>'.$aDoor[$index].': '.$variety. '</div>';
}
```

If you have a unique identifier for each of your varieties I would recommend manually indexing your form elements for clarity instead:

```
<form action="cart.php">
    <?php 
    echo'<input style="width:10px; margin-left:9px; " name="price[' . $variety['id'] . ']" type="checkbox" value="' . $variety['price']. '"  />
         <input name="variety[' . $variety['id'] . ']" type="hidden" value="' . $variety['variety']. '"  />';
    ?>
</form>
```

and then looping through them the same as above.

Comment: thank you. 
I like the idea of using the id and then the index

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is always one variety for every price, you can use `array_combine()` with the first parameter being the keys (the variety in this case) and the second being the values (the price).:

```
$price_list = array_combine($_POST['variety'], $_POST['price']);
```

Then if you want to print this out you can do:

```
foreach($price_list as $item => $price) {
echo "<dt>$item</dt><dd>$price</dd>"; 
}
```

Comment: I have to say that array_combine Both parameters should have an equal number of elements and strangely variety is passing three elements and price only the two I have chosen. I don't know if it is because the input type in variety index is "hidden". It is because of that. The form only hast three input checkboxes. the checkboxes are visibles and the user can choose any of then but the varieties are hidden therefore it is passing the three elements or all the index values to cart.php. Do you understand what I say?

Comment: If a checkbox in a form is NOT checked when the form is submitted, its 'name' is not included in the submitted data.